# php bin/magento reindexer:reindex catalogrule_product

Tags: error

I am using Wampserver 3.0 on Windows 10 and I have installed Magento 2.0.
I extracted Magento to C:\wamp64\www and installed. I had an initial issue with the php.ini which I have since solved. So now it appears that everything installed correctly but I am getting [image: This is the screen it takes me to when I click on the hyperlink in the error message: indexers are invalid][image: This is the result when trying to re-index from the cmd line]

How do I resolve this issue? Thank you for your assistance.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Magento error but an error with your PHP path. This seems to be a common error with Windows PHP cli, try navigating to your PHP dir and run it from there, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446186/cannot-run-php-from-command-line-when-use-environment-variable).